# comments in joomla

Tags: joomla

i'm new to joomla and i wanna know how can i install modules(or whatever they call)..i downloaded Jcomments from Joomlatune and i donno how to install or configure it..the documentation is also not good plus the screenshots are in a different language..
can someone help me in installing that module?
also, how can i enable comments for an article?
thanks...

Comment: Sam, did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're having problems because you didn't understand Joomla's terminology to extensions.

Extensions are divided in:

- Modules
- Plugins
- Components

Check [official documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial:Joomla_Beginning_Developer_Course#Definitions) to learn each concept.

So, when you have an extension, to install it you just go to your Joomla's menu in administration, and select install like it is in the picture below.

[image: Installing Joomla's Extensions]

Then, select your zip file which contains your extension.

Answer (score 0):

Go to yourserver.com/administrator/

In one of the menus is a component manager.

Comment: there is nothing like a component manager..only plugin manager and module manager.which one u meant..does joomla support comments by default like drupal?